# Perl - how variable Interpolation and backlashes (escaping) works in substitution regexes, specifically replacement part

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, interpolation, substitution

I am trying to understand what happens when a variable OR backslash OR variable containing backlash is put into a regex substitution, for example `s/$var1/$var2/` or `s/abc\\/xyz\\/` , etc...

This is what I tried:

```
use Modern::Perl; no strict;

$bs_a = "\\_a";
$bs_b = "\\_b";

$str_to_substitute = "C:\\tmp\\_a";
### I'm gonna change this string to C:\tmp\_b by regex substitution
### pattern part: $bs_a, replacement part: $bs_b
### using the whole strings instead of just s/a/b/ because for example
### I may have many such string pairs for substitutions in an external file

#1
$result = $str_to_substitute =~ s/\\_a/\\_b/r; 
say $result;  # C:\tmp\_b    ... OK

#2
$result = $str_to_substitute =~ s/\\_a/$bs_b/r; # 
say $result;  # C:\tmp\_b    ... OK

#3
$result = $str_to_substitute =~ s/$bs_a/$bs_b/r; # 
say $result;  # C:\tmp\\_b    ... why?? what is the difference between #1 and #3

#4
$result = $str_to_substitute =~ s'$bs_a'$bs_b'r; 
say $result; # $bs_a is literally '$bs_a', $bs_b also is literal

#5
$result = $str_to_substitute =~ s/$bs_a/\\_b/r;
say $result; # C:\tmp\\_b    ?? what is the difference between #1 and #5 (and #3)
```

What I was thinking is that the replacement doesn't do any escaping at all. (the pattern part does)

Now I am really confused and I don't understand why the results #1,#3 and the results #1,#5 are different.

- Does anybody know why?
- Does anybody know good easily understandable source :-) on what happens when I put variables and backlashes in the replacement part? (or in the pattern part as well but regarding substitution)

Comment: Using `no strict` is a very bad choice.

Comment: If you are editing windows paths, there are much better ways. You can, for example, use regular slash instead: `c:/tmp/_b`, and the path will work. There are also modules that might be better to use. Fiddling around with double interpolations is bound to give you headaches.

Comment: I tend to use `no strict` If I just want to try a specific thing on a very small scale. But you're right... you can then get confused, e.g. because of mistyped variable, even with few lines of code. I am just being lazy here. I used here Modern::Perl because I wanted /r - nondestructive substitution and say(), and no strict because I didn't want to bother with typing my.

Comment: >If you are editing windows paths...

I've run into this problem when reading paths in ,jsons (like transform_from.json and transform_to.json) There were even two backlashes instead of one in paths.
I solved my problem somehow. But then I tried to get better understanding of how things work.

Comment: What is the overall objective? Working with paths (in Windows) ?  It is always, always a good idea to avoid messing with slashes. Good question

Comment: @zdim 1}part of explanation
objective is frequent copying of https://www.elgato.com/en/stream-deck settings from one PC to another.
Stream deck is a great device for creating macros (among other things). With SD you automate things like keystrokes and simple actions or if things get complicated to run for example an autohotkey macro. 
SD has its settings in .json files in its APPDATA folder. There are so called profiles, typically every application can have its profile and SD switches profile based on what's running in foreground. Every profile has its .json.file

Comment: 2) part: In the .json file there's also the full path of the app. The thing is in order for its automatic profile switching to work the app paths have to exactly match what's on the current computer. And I sometimes have different paths, e.g. 
"C:\\totalcmd\\TOTALCMD64.EXE" and "C:\\Program Files\\totalcmd\\TOTALCMD64.EXE". So I've written myself a perl tool which reads paths from a config file and converts them (I have 3 PCs, applications can have different locations on them, so each PC has its own "config")
The tool probably works. But the replacement part doesn't look too nice :-)

Comment: Alright then, so you do need to work with paths, plainly put, and I'd recommend to use a library.  I answered your question here, on regex and backslashes (let me know if something's unclear there) -- but really I'd say that you want to parse your paths using a library for that and then manipulating parts will be trivial.  It may well be that you'll never have to touch the backslash character on the keyboard.

Comment: Example, at a risk of saying what you know or isn't what you need -- `perl -MFile::Spec -wE'$p=q(C::\\Win\\Some); say for File::Spec->splitdir($p)` prints lines `C`,`Win`,`Some`.  Same with single slashes, or with forward slashes.  Then `catdir` can reassemble a list of components into a path.  (This `File::Spec` determines what system you're on, so when trying that out in Linux I have to explicitly use `File::Spec::Win32` everywhere.)

Comment: And then there's [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) (with its workhorse`Path::Class::Dir` and `Path::Class::File`), with a whole lot more.  See also the handy [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases #3 and #5, with the same output, the regex pattern is a variable that was assigned a double-quoted string, which had thus been evaluated and had undergone string interpolation; so it *has one backslash* character and the variable (pattern) is `\_a`.

So `\_a` from the input string is matched and replaced, while the other `\` in input remains.

In case #1 the backslashes are right in the pattern, and by the [details of the regex parsing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#the-replacement-of-s///) one is skipped but retained. So the pattern has both `\` and `\_a`, which are matched and replaced.

Example:

```
say "\\_a" =~ s{ \\_ }{X}gxr;  #--> Xa

my $p = "\\_";
say "\\_a" =~ s{ $p }{X}gxr;  #--> \Xa
```

The replacement side is always interpolated as a double-quoted string, even when given as/with a string literal. (Well, subject to some modifiers and delimiters.)

---

I'd like to add that there are various tools at our disposal that help us avoid messing with slashes, what is always a good idea. (Doubly-so for double slashes :)

For one, there are libraries for working with paths, what this seems to be about, in which case you may not need a regex at all; see [File::Spec](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Spec), [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class), and the overall handy [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

For regex, there is [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta)'s escapes `\Q...\E`, which may help to cleanly target those backslashes without worrying about their special and/or partly-special actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!
And also for the link to the relevant part of the docs.

Comment: Welcome -- here are a few more generally useful links for this: [regex substitution in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer) (note that `perlop` has a lot of things one may expect elsewhere, like for regex, `qx`, [various quoting](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) in general, etc); [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#The-backslash); and then of course [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) and [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) (a fairly thorough "tutorial" I think)

Comment: it''s crazy :-)
I'm trying to go slowly through patterns ( `use re 'debug'` )
I think that when you do `say "\\_a" =~ s{ $p }{X}gxr;  #--> \_a` you're actually matching a single space.
 `say "\\_a" =~ s{$p}{X}gxr;  #--> \_a`  generates error Trailing \ in regex m/\/

Comment: @JanPtáčník Ah, but of course!  That's because the pattern ends up being a single ``\`` and that isn't possible to have as a last thing in a regex pattern (so the space after helps so that it is allowed).  So the point still stands but the example with only slashes isn't good!  Will update.  Thank you, a good catch!

Comment: @JanPtáčník Updated, with the example pattern now being `\\_`. (Not as simple as I'd like but I hope that it still conveys the point?) I still leave spaces `{ $p }` but now it works without them as well.

Comment: @JanPtáčník Crazy indeed, how the space that "doesn't matter" (with `/x`) matters for parsing :)

Comment: It's difficult to come up with really simplified examples that still convey the point. I couldn't. You've managed it quite well.